# Use normal Yaru theme variant in 21.10

Tags: themes

With the Upgrade from 21.04 to 21.10, it seems we can no longer choose a standard Yaru theme variant but only light or dark.

Is there any possibility to get the normal variant back? (Mostly light themed but with dark top bars in applications.)

Comment: Since 20.10 uses the newer Gnome 40 maybe it will take some time before things like this are upgraded.

Comment: https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/07/ubuntu-21-10-release-features

Comment: Thanks, @David ! Your article led me to [this explanation](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2021/06/ubuntu-21-10-yarn-theme-change) and [this analysis on github](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/discussions/2677), which explain the situation more fully. Also, two related issues: [1](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/issues/2913), [2](https://github.com/ubuntu/yaru/pull/2922)

Comment: It is not really an answer so I will not make it one. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem, I really liked the mixed theme, the regular light and dark are just ugly to me. I managed to "hack it back" with the following steps:

1. Install Ubuntu 21.04 as a Virtual Machine (or on a regular machine).
2. Export the following directories from your 21.04 Ubuntu: /usr/share/themes/Yaru , /usr/share/themes/Yaru-light , /usr/share/themes/Yaru-dark
3. Copy the exported folders to ~/.themes on your 21.10 Ubuntu system.
4. Enjoy! :)

Comment: Apparently you like users to break their systems manipulating core system directories by hand. Instead, copy these folders from 21.04 to your local ~/.share/themes folder, where it will override the system default theme because of the same name, and where it will not be overwritten by the next system update. You may want to update your answer to reflect that better practice.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know I can override themes that way. Better practice for sure. I updated my answer.